# Shuddering & delayed stopping when pulling in to parking place turning right

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, braking

When turning sharply to the right when pulling in to a parking place, there is a shuddering and delayed stop.

ABS light has come on intermittently.

FIXD shows nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest you look at your brakes. Ensure you check the brake pad thickness on both sides of the rotor. This is for *both* sides of the front end.

Comment: Have you used a code reader, or better yet a diagnostic computer to see if your ABS system is has intermittent sensors? Sometimes there will be codes for ABS which do not get flagged with a check engine light. I have had similar problems, including sporadic triggering of one wheel ABS.  The ABS system logged errors, and pointed me to the correct sensor.

Comment: Mongo, The only diagnostic device I have is FIXD, which does not show ABS. I've seen what you are talking about on Youtube.

Is there an affordable device that you recommend? I doubt parts stores will loan that out.

I saw somewhere where the senor that is broken is opposite the side that the problem seem to be on.

I also saw someone using a volt meter on the sensor while the hub is turned- a voltage output was shown.

Mongo,Thank you.

Comment: Paulster,All new pads and rotors.  Happened before and after replacements.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Abs sensor first place i would check I had similar issue when i replaced the wheel bearing,after checking my work made sure everything was up to specs.
And still had that issue i took out the sensor have a closer look and the sensor had a hair line crack on the casing.went to wrecking yard found the newest compatable sensor put it on in the parking lot ,all things back to normal.